# Stop user from navigating away after entering data on form elements loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has it's elements loaded via Ajax in the following html structure.

```
<div id="form-wrapper"><form id="myform" action="#" method="post">

//form elements loaded via ajax.

</form></div>
```

I am using the following code to display a warning message when user navigates away from the page with unsaved data on it. This does not work.

```
function confirm_page_unload(on) {
window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? confirm_page_navigate_dialog : null;
}
function confirm_page_navigate_dialog() {
return 'You have entered data on the current page. Navigating away without first   saving your data will result in all changes to be lost.';
}
jQuery('#myform:input').on('change', '#form-wrapper', function() { confirm_page_unload(true); });
```

It appears to me that the issue pertains to the form elements being loaded via ajax. How can I get this to work. I am using jQuery 1.7, hence I have used on().

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap `#myform:input` with `#form-wrapper` in your .on call.  The first item should be the static container on your page that does not change after the initial DOM load.

On closer look, perhaps you meant `#myform :input`?  In other words, an input inside of myform, not myform itself.  So try this:

```
jQuery('#form-wrapper').on('change', '#myform :input', function() { confirm_page_unload(true); });
```

Comment: Swapping the selectors and adding the space resolved the issue. And btw, I was intending the input inside of the form. I appreciate the help!